# Haskell stack - allow-newer enabled and won't turn off?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

According to [the docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#allow-newer), `allow-newer` is an option in `package.yaml` which tells stack to ignore bounds on dependency versions specified in the `cabal` file. Despite the fact that it should be disabled by default, I get the following weird error message when building:

```
WARNING: Ignoring <Project name>'s bounds on Persistence (>2.0); using Persistence-2.0.
Reason: allow-newer enabled.
WARNING: Ignoring <Project name>'s bounds on binary (>0.8.6.0); using binary-0.8.6.0.
Reason: allow-newer enabled.
```

To try to fix this I added `allow-newer: false` to `package.yaml`, but that only resulted in

```
/path/to/project/package.yaml: Ignoring unrecognized field $.allow-newer
```

as well as the other error messages mentioned above.

What could be going wrong here? I'm using `stack` version 2.1.3.

`stack.yaml` (comments ommitted):

```
resolver: lts-14.0

packages:
- .

extra-deps:
- Persistence-2.0@sha256:997664d1805105f10202b6148cb3cfd57fa1e298be5b21e9fa97108bfb8f7918,2093
```

Comment: Could you copy over your whole `stack.yaml` file? It may help to diagnose if e.g. you’ve made a syntax error or some similar problem.

Comment: @bradrn added the file. I noticed that I had previously included `Persistence-2.0` in the `extra-deps` field. I don't remember what that was meant to solve, but I suppose it could be causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks @EbenCowley! But I think I wasn’t quite clear enough with what I was asking: I wanted to see your `stack.yaml` _with the `allow-newer` field_, in order to check the syntax of that field as you have written it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc you link to is a list of options for `stack.yaml`, not `package.yaml` (which is not really part of stack, but of a different tool called hpack). If allow-newer is not in your `stack.yaml`, another place it could hide is `$HOME/.stack/config.yaml`.